# saving image in byte array in php

Tags: php, arrays

how can save an image file into byte array. i post the image file  to server as base64. and tehn convert to jpg. but i dont know how can convert to bytearray from JPG

```
$base=$_POST["image"];

$binary=base64_decode($base);
$file = fopen("image.jpg", "w");
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the file in binary mode...

```
$file = fopen("image.jpg", "wb");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `imagecreatefromstring()` function: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

(the example on that page is very similar to your code)